# Questions and footnotes on the bottom of the page

Tags: footnotes

I'm trying to re-format some discussion article (old *Watchtower* article) I found into a two-column article. It has questions before the paragraphs and I want to reformat it into its modern design where the questions are in the bottom of the page (like a footnote) instead of appearing before the paragraph itself, is there a way to do it without overriding the footnote itself?

I'm not really good at explaining details but this is how I am planning to format my document:

```
1. Paragraph paragraph   3. Paragraph paragraph para-
paragraph paragraph pa-     graph paragraph paragraph
paragraph paragraph pa-     text text text text text
ragraph words words wo-     text text tex tex tex tex
rds words words words       TeX TeX TeX TeX TeX TeX
words words words words     LaTeX LaTeX LaTeX LaTeX

2. things things things  4. stack over flow stack over
things things things        stack over flow stack over
things things things wi-    flow stack over flow steak
ngs wings wings wings       over flow etc etc etc etc
random random random ran-   etc etc etc etc etc etc etc
dom*                        etc etc etc etc etc etc etc
----
*random footnote
----
1. Question question      3. Another Question
2. Inquiry inquiry        4. Another another question
inquiry
```

Note how the questions and footnotes has their own section of place. I will try to clarify things to the best of my abilities but if the figure was not clear enough this is exactly what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TeX.SE... Hope the below may helps you...

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[]{manyfoot}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}[alph]

\begin{document}

This is for test\footnote{\lipsum[1]}\footnoteA{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[1-2]

This is for test\footnote{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[3-4]

This is for test\footnote{\lipsum[3]}\lipsum[5-6]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! It did help me clarify how to add footnotes, but what I am trying to achieve is kind of a different section of footnotes. The screenshot shows a section for the actual footnote and then a divider and then another section for questions. I want to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: Adding a second divider is easy, as is changing the font.  I don't see an easy way to change the \footnotemark though.

Comment: Believe `\SetFootnoteHook{\tiny}` is the tag to change the `\footnotemark`

Answer (score 0):

A modified version of MadyYum's answer.  Note that `\@makefntext` is defined in the document class.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[]{manyfoot}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\myfntext}[1]{% to replace \@makefntext
    \parindent 1em%
    \noindent
    \hbox to 1.8em{\normalfont\@thefnmark.\hfil}#1}
\newcommand{\resetmark}{\let\@makefntext\myfntext}
\makeatother

\SelectFootnoteRule{default}
\SetFootnoteHook{\resetmark\normalsize}
\DeclareNewFootnote{A}

\begin{document}

This is for test\footnote{\textit{\lipsum[1]}}

\refstepcounter{footnoteA}%
Question \thefootnoteA.~\footnotetextA{\lipsum[1]}

\lipsum[1-2]

This is for test\footnote{\lipsum[2]}\lipsum[3-4]

This is for test\footnote{\lipsum[3]}\lipsum[5-6]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on this using the `bigfoot` package (which is just a superset of `manyfoot`) and a quite unconventional use of `xsim`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}
\usepackage{bigfoot}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\DeclareExerciseProperty{par}
\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{footnote}{}{}
\makeatletter
\xsimsetup{
  exercise/template=footnote,
  exercise/print=false,
  exercise/print-false-hook=
    \renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{#1}%
    \footnotetextquestion{%
      \sffamily
      \GetExercisePropertyTF{par}{#1 }{\arabic{par}. }
      \GetExerciseProperty{exercise-body}%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\DeclareNewFootnote{default}
\SelectFootnoteRule{default}
\DeclareNewFootnote{question}
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\newcounter{par}
\newcommand\setpar{%
  \leavevmode
  \stepcounter{par}%
  \llap{\textsuperscript{\arabic{par}}\space}%
}
\renewcommand\thepar{\arabic{par}.}

\begin{document}

\setpar\lipsum[1]\footnote{random footnote}
\begin{exercise}
  Question question
\end{exercise}

\setpar\lipsum[2]
\setpar\lipsum[3]
\begin{exercise}[par={2, 3.}]
  Inquiry inquiry inquiry
\end{exercise}

\setpar\lipsum[4]
\setpar\lipsum[5]
\begin{exercise}[par={4, 5.}]
  (a) Another question. (b) And even more questions.
\end{exercise}

\setpar\lipsum[6]\footnote{Some footnote}

\setpar\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

[image]